# What are "parameters" and how do they prevent SQL injections?

Tags: sql

I'm very early on in learning SQL, but I've encountered the topic of SQL injections, and understand that parameters are probably the best way to prevent them. But I couldn't find any explanation of what they actually ARE.

So, for instance, in this code in ASP.NET (from w3schools):

```
txtUserId = getRequestString("UserId");
sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @0";
command = new SqlCommand(sql);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0",txtUserID);
command.ExecuteReader();
```

What dos the "command.parameters.addwithvalue" actually do?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer to it - everywhere I look they just say "use parameters" but don't explain what that actually means...

Thanks!

Comment: Well... `AddWithValue` is a method in the Ado.Net library. You might want to do some research on that method. It then leads on to other things like the parameters collection. I also suggest you run your code and inspect program variables during runtime and see if you can make sense of that.

Answer (score 0):

actually you need to make prepared statement to stop sql injection , another thing is you need to escape the query or add slashed before single quotes in order to qvoid SQL Injection

Form w3schools

> "Some web developers use a "blacklist" of words or characters to
>   search for in SQL input, to prevent SQL injection attacks.
>
> This is not a very good idea. Many of these words (like delete or
>   drop) and characters (like semicolons and quotation marks), are used
>   in common language, and should be allowed in many types of input.
>
> (In fact it should be perfectly legal to input an SQL statement in a
>   database field.)
>
> The only proven way to protect a web site from SQL injection attacks,
>   is to use SQL parameters.
>
> SQL parameters are values that are added to an SQL query at execution
>   time, in a controlled manner.
>
> ASP.NET Razor Example
>
> txtUserId = getRequestString("UserId"); txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users
>   WHERE UserId = @0"; db.Execute(txtSQL,txtUserId);
>
> Note that parameters are represented in the SQL statement by a @
>   marker.
>
> The SQL engine checks each parameter to ensure that it is correct for
>   its column and are treated literally, and not as part of the SQL to be
>   executed. Another Example txtNam = getRequestString("CustomerName");
>   txtAdd = getRequestString("Address"); txtCit =
>   getRequestString("City"); txtSQL = "INSERT INTO Customers
>   (CustomerName,Address,City) Values(@0,@1,@2)";
>   db.Execute(txtSQL,txtNam,txtAdd,txtCit);"